# National characters in manpages

Tags: freebsd, man, i18n

I am trying to get a proper display of national characters with FreeBSD **man**.
I have tried running the following on 8.1 and 9.0:

```
# PAGER=less LANG="pl_PL.UTF-8" man -d -M. ./man.1
-- Using architecture: i386:i386
-- Using pager: less
-- Using manual sections: 1:1aout:8:2:3:n:4:5:6:7:9:l
-- Using locale paths: pl_PL.UTF-8:pl.UTF-8:en.UTF-8:.
-- Using standard page width
-- Searching for ./man.1
-- Found a usable page, displaying that
-- Command: /usr/bin/zcat -f ./man.1 | tbl | groff -S -P-h -Wall -mtty-char -man -Tascii -P-c | less
```

But it prints:

> Program man jest systemowA przeglAdarkA stron  podrAcznika  ekranowego.KaA1/4dy argument...

The same manpage displays properly on a Linux host:

> Program man jest systemową przeglądarką stron podręcznika ekranowego. Każdy
>   argument...

I have been told by a knowledgeable person that manpages on 9.0 *are supposed* to display properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing having `LESSCHARSET=utf-8` in your environment. At least on my FreeBSD host using this setting allows me to view the manual pages in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Tascii` argument to `groff` looks suspicious.

On further investigation, it seems `man` sets this parameter based on where in the MANPATH it found the man page.

For example, on my system, `-Tutf8` is used whenever the debug output shows

```
Found manpage /usr/share/man/en.UTF-8/man1/...
```

but `-Tascii` is used when it shows

```
Found manpage /usr/share/man/man1/...
```

In this case, I think the problem is that `man` doesn't see any locale name in the path to the man page, so it defaults to ASCII/C locale.

As a workaround, try this:

```
mkdir -p pl.UTF-8/man1
cp man.1 pl.UTF-8/man
man -d -M. man
```